# Partial views in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-routing

I'm new to Angular and would appreciate any advice.
Basically, I have one-to-many relationship- one `Category` has several `Product`, 
I have the layout page where I render different partial views:

```
<div class="mainContent">
     <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```

My **first** view shows the list of categories, when one of them is clicked, I show the **second** view, which is separated to two parts: list of categories, and list of products of particular category, schematically it looks like:

[image]

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to use another partial for the list of products because want to keep them in separate .html.

I configured routes:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/category', {
        templateUrl: 'category.html',
        controller: 'categoryController as catCtrl'
    })
    .when('/category/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'categoryDetail.html',
        controller: 'categoryDetailController as catDetailCtrl'
    })       
    .when('/product/:category_id', {
        templateUrl: 'product.html',
        controller: 'productController as productCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/category"
    });
});
```

And controllers:

```
app.controller("categoryController", function($http)
{
    var vm = this;
    vm.categories = somedata;
});
app.controller("categoryDetailController", function($http, $routeParams)
{
   var vm = this;
   vm.category = somedata;//current category from REST api, using $routeParams.id
});
app.controller("productController", function($http, $routeParams)
{
   var vm = this;
   vm.products = somedata;//product list of current category using $routeParams.category_id
});
```

So on my **first** view - `category.html`, I have the list of categories with hrefs:

```
<a href="#/category/{{category.id}}">
```

On the **second** - `categoryDetail.html`, I list categories again but with another hrefs:

```
<a href="#/product/{{category.id}}">
```

And on the **last** view - `product.html` I list the products.

Till now, when I click on category inside `categoryDetail.html` my `product.html` renders in `mainContent` div of the layout, instead - I need it to render as inner partial inside `categoryDetail.html`. I tried to use `<ng-view>` again, but this does not seem to be correct.

Comment: Any particular reason why you aren't making use of states? i.e. angular-ui-router? Also - +1 for the image

Comment: Have you considered using ngInclude instead of ngView?

Comment: @Katana24, i've read that ui-router is used for larger apps, mine is quite small, but should I use ui-router if I need paging for products list?

Answer (score 8):

there are couple ways for partials in AngularJS.

**ng-include**

If theres no logic, or it will be provided from parent scope you can just include a html file into your view.

Example:

```
<div ng-include="'/path/to/your/file.html'"></div>
```

**new directive**

If you'll have a bit logic in your partial, and you'd like to use it as a separate module in your app - I'll strongly advice to built a new directive.

[Example.](http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/)

PS. If you're new to Angular, [this](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) may be useful :-)

Comment: It's important to note the double quotes around the single quotes in the case of using `ng-include`